# Do flashlights have any impairment on AI?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Prior to purchasing a new flashlight for my shiny new Assault SMG, do flashlights impair AI ?  Do they reduce accuracy of the AI in any form?  Will they revel my location if used when stealthed (and unnoticed)?

Comment: I'm 99% sure they'll affect stealth, but are obviously only on when you aim so not that big of a deal.  I only surmise this as I've found it easier to escape the police at night by hiding and turning off the car lights.  If I leave them on I tend to get found easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a flashlight on your weapon will make your enemies find you easier (I tested this myself a while ago, i was curious just like you) and personally i find the flashlight to make difficult to see sometimes because it gives too much bright to the scene so i ended removing it.